# How to increment this vector: v = [1ˆ2, 3ˆ2, 5ˆ2, ..., (2n+1)ˆ2] with given pattern (in description)

Tags: matlab, vector, increment

I am lost as to how to increment this vector. I know that the value from each number squared increase by odd numbers starting from 3. From 1^2 to 2^2 we have a space of three, from 2^2 to 3^2 we have a space of 5 in between and then 7 in between for 3^2 to 4^2 and 9 in between 4^2 and 5^2 and so on and so forth. But I just can't think of how I would write those increments for a general case as I have to do in this given problem.

Comment: You want the increment between two elements in this vector? That would be `(2n+1)^2-(2n-1)^2`.

Comment: I was really trying to say that if I tried to write this using a:d:b vector, what would i put for the part that requires the increment "d"?

Comment: `(1:2:2n+1).^2` ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define `d` in the `a:d:b` vector with one formula because it changes constantly. Therefore, you need to define your vector as [1 3 5 7 ... 2n+1] and square it.

```
(1:2:2*n+1).^2

ans =

     1     9    25    49    81   121
```

Comment: @Ineedhelp Is this what you expected?